# I want to float a flush bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flushbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTmyV.png)

I also added dependency on flushbar to Yaml.

Also import Flushbar helper carried out.

However, I don't know why the error occurs in the container part.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `body: Container(`.